# APIGateway mapping header to path via proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to proxy a request though API gateway to an internal service.
My external request looks like:

Path: `/resources`
Headers: `owner_id` passed along which was decoded via an authorizer in a previous step.

The proxied endpoint I would like to hit is:
`/owner/{owner_id}/resources`

Is it possible to pull a header out and use this as a path parameter to the internal API?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set an Endpoint URL like `http://httpbin.org/anything/{owner_id}`/blah1/blah2 in `Integration Request`
2. in the same `Integration Request`, add a `Mapping Templates` : "When there are not templates defined (recommended)) section, add a Content-Type : application/json with a template body of `#set($context.requestOverride.path.owner_id = $input.params("owner_id"))`

See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference